# Fit 3 linear models to data

Tags: python, linear-regression, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have n points without any specific order which all lie on three possible hyperplanes with some noise, I want to split them into 3 sets of points such that solving linear regression on each of them will minimize the sum of errors.

Is there any known algorithm I can implement or a python library that does this? I didn't find anything about this problem.

Probably an EM algorithm with enough initial gusses like in k-means would work here but is there any better way to do it? And is there any library with a function that does it? I didn't find anything but maybe its because I don't know the name of the problem, because it sounds to me like a sort of basic problem that there will be a lot of existing methods for already.

Comment: Without any extra information K-means + LLS seems a good way to proceednat a first glance. Have you tried so far? Do you encounter any issue when performing it? What is the dimensionality of the problem? How big is the observation set?